# Formula to calculate discounts

Tags: formula-field, opportunity-lineitem

I have more than one discount in my opportunity line item.

How can I calculate the total in discounts in formula field?

like Unit price =100
     Discount1 = 10%
     Discount2 = 10%
     Total=81

I found this formula, but work just to one discount:

```
Round({!Unitprice}-{!Unitprice}*{!Discount},2)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried any formula yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Unit_Price__c - ((Unit_Price__c * Discount_One__c) + ((Unit_Price__c - (Unit_Price__c * Discount_One__c)) * Discount_Two__c))
```

---

This should work like a math problem. Calculate your first value from the original discount:

```
(Unit_Price__c * Discount_One__c)
```

and then calculate the value from the second discount by calculating the remaining value from the first discount and multiplying it by the second discount:

```
((Unit_Price__c - (Unit_Price__c * Discount_One__c)) * Discount_Two__c)
```

Add both of those values together:

```
((Unit_Price__c * Discount_One__c) + ((Unit_Price__c - (Unit_Price__c * Discount_One__c)) * Discount_Two__c))
```

and subtract all of that from the original unit price.

```
Unit_Price__c - ((Unit_Price__c * Discount_One__c) + ((Unit_Price__c - (Unit_Price__c * Discount_One__c)) * Discount_Two__c))
```

Comment: I'm sorry is Total Price not Unit price, i'm sorry for the error.
But if I insert a new discount, the count is different.

TotalPrice - ((TotalPrice * Discount__c)+ ((TotalPrice - (TotalPrice * Discount__c)) * Discount1__c)+ ((TotalPrice - ((TotalPrice -(TotalPrice * Discount__c)) * Discount1__c)) * Discount2__c))

It's rounding problems? This formula have some error?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. I gave you an example, you will need to take it form there. I didn't realize this needed to work for X amount of discounts.

Comment: Yes, I use your formula and work fine, but with more one discount give me 71,9 instead of 72,9. 
You think that this formula is incorrect?
I appreciate so much your help.
Thank you.